Creating custom chess symbols (custom image) in LaTeX that remain compatible with xskak or chessboard packages for FEN positions
I want to use custom chess piece images/icons in my LaTeX document, but I still need to be able to utilize the xskak or chessboard packages for displaying FEN positions. What is the best approach or style to create custom chess symbols that remain compatible with these packages?

Welcome! The packages use fonts with specialist encodings, so you would need to create a custom font or fonts with suitable encoding(s). The code isn't set up to use images/icons, but glyphs. If you want to try it, open one of the chess fonts in a font editor (e.g. FontForge) to see how it is done.

sorry but it is completly unclear what you mean by "compatible" and how and where you want to use your symbols.

Custom font, yeah, that's what I thought. Then I just have to make sure to ship it inside the PDF, right. FontForge, gotta check it out, thank you for the comment.

There is always metafont (see the simpsons package).

Is there a way to add symbols with multiple colors? Creating a font in SVG-OT format is extremely overwhelming.
